# Automake: AM_CFLAGS has no effect

Tags: unix, gcc, compilation, autotools, automake

I am trying to add some compilation options in Automake, but none of the approaches work.

Here is my `configure.ac`:

```
AC_INIT(...)
AC_PREREQ([2.59])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.10 foreign -Wall no-define])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile test/Makefile])
AC_LANG(C++)
AC_OUTPUT
```

And I have the parent `Makefile.am` (in top-level dir):

```
#AM_CFLAGS = ... # doesn't work
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}
SUBDIRS = src test
dist_noinst_SCRIPTS = autogen.sh
```

and a `Makefile.am` for each source dir; `src/Makefile`:

```
include_HEADERS = ...
lib_LIBRARIES = ...
```

and `test/Makefile`:

```
#AM_CFLAGS = ... # doesn't work
bin_PROGRAMS = myprog #test
myprog_SOURCES = ...
myprog_LDADD = ../src/libmylib.a
#myprog_CFLAGS = ... # Doesn't work either
```

I tried uncommenting all combinations of commented lines, i.e.:

- add `AM_CFLAGS = ...` to the parent `Makefile.am` - this should set the CFLAGS for all affected sources
- add `AM_CFLAGS = ...` to other two `Makefile.am`s
- add myprog_`CFLAGS = ...` to Makefile.am (this should set CFLAGS when compiling myprog)

but none of these has any effects. Both my program (`myprog`) and its library (`mylib`) are kept being compiled / linked with some default flags which are something like `-DHAVE_CONFIG -g -O2`.

I also tried using `INCLUDES` instead of `AM_CFLAGS`, but didn't help.

Anybody has some idea what is going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It looks like you're compiling C++, in which case the variable to use is `AM_CXXFLAGS`.
2. Setting `AM_CXXFLAGS` should be in the `Makefile.am` that declares things you're actually compiling (i.e., `bin_PROGRAMS`, `lib_LTLIBRARIES`, ...).
3. If you're repeating yourself, don't forget automake supports an `include` statement.
4. Recursive make considered harmful. Modern automake supports `subdir-objects`. If one `Makefile.am` gets out of hand, use `include` statements.
5. The modern way to turn on libtool is `LT_INIT`, not `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL`.
6. `AC_LANG(C++)` doesn't do anything at point of `configure.ac`. It sets the language to use when running configure tests. Besides, `AC_LANG_PUSH` and `AC_LANG_POP` are smarter ways of doing that.
7. Why are you assigning to `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS` like that?

Comment: Thanks. Btw, what do you mean by 7., what would you do instead? I am new to autotools.

Comment: No worries. `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS` is where you set extra flags to be passed to `aclocal` (usually something like `-I m4`, if you've got a directory of custom macros). If you're not setting `ACLOCAL_FLAGS`, there shouldn't be a need for that line at all.

Answer (score -1):

I tried adding `AM_CFLAGS` to the parent Makefile.am as suggested, which didn't work.  When I added it to the relevant Makefile.am, it ended introducing two conflicting `-g` options as shown below:

```
libtool: link: gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O0 -g -O2 -Wl -pthread ...
```

The correct way to disable optimization is to add `CFLAGS = -g -O0` to the Makefile.am where it's needed. Try deleting Makefile.in and Makefile (no extension) if the change doesn't take effect for some reason.

Here's the correct linker directive:

```
libtool: link: gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O0 -Wl -pthread ...
```

Comment: "*The correct way to disable optimization is to add `CFLAGS = -g -O0` to the Makefile.am*" That gives a warning: "'CFLAGS' is a user variable, you should not override it; use 'AM_CFLAGS' instead"